# Why is System.in declared as nullInputStream() instead of null?

Tags: java

In the [`System`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java) class, `in`, `out`, and `err` are static fields. These fields are declared for example:

```
 public final static InputStream in = nullInputStream();
```

Why declare [`nullInputStream()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.nullPrintStream%28%29) instead of `null`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The source code has the following comment:

```
/**
 * The following two methods exist because in, out, and err must be
 * initialized to null.  The compiler, however, cannot be permitted to
 * inline access to them, since they are later set to more sensible values
 * by initializeSystemClass().
 */
```

In short, since `System.in` is a `static final` variable, if it was set to `null`, the compiler would consider it as a constant, and would replace all the references to `System.in` in other classes with `null` (that's what inlining means). Which would obviously make everything non-functional. Some native code must be used to replace the value of this `System.in` final value (which normally should never change) once the system is initialized.

To resume: it's used to avoid a compiler optimization that should not be made in this very particular case, because System.in is a final field that can change, which is normally impossible.

Comment: you are right, there is `public static void setIn(InputStream in)` and it invokes `private static native void setIn0(InputStream in);`

Comment: what is purpose of setIno(InputStream in) and setOut(PrintStream out)

Comment: This is not correct. `null` is _not_ a compile time constant!

Comment: @Arendv.Reinersdorff: Then either the compiler inlines non compile-time constants, or this nullInputStream() trick is unnecessary. What's your explanation? Is it the reason why it's simply set to null in JDK7?

Answer (score -1):

**You are wrong.**

In Java source code it is written as

```
 public final static InputStream in = null;
```

not

```
 public final static InputStream in = nullInputStream();
```

You can take reference of the source code for the `System`  class [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/System.java.html).

Comment: Please check it below public final class System {
    /* First thing---register the natives */
    private static native void registerNatives();
    static {
        registerNatives();
    }
    /** Don't let anyone instantiate this class */
    private System() {
    }
    /**
     * The "standard" input stream. This stream is already
     * open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream
     * corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by
     * the host environment or user.
     */
 public final static InputStream in = nullInputStream();

Comment: From where you have taken source reference ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: He's not wrong. He's just looking at JDK 6 source code, and you're looking at JDK 7.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani In Oracle JDK6, it is `nullInputStream();`.

Comment: Doesn't that beg the question then -- **how come** it works with `null` in Java 7?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - it could be a special a compiler hack that causes it to treat that particular compile-time constant differently.

Comment: @StephenC Just went to the JLS, it's in fact quite obvious -- only values of primitive type or String can be compile-time constants. That would mean that `System.out` **never** needed a special dummy value to avoid it becoming a compile-time constant!